# Core Plot - iOS - Highlight region between 2 plotted lines

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using the Core Plot library (V1.0) in my iOS app.

I need to highlight area between the two drawn lines. Can anybody help?

Here is the output I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Also, is there any alternative library which can give me above output.

Answer (score 1):

With opaque fills as shown in your example graph, Core Plot will work just fine. As long as the lower plot is added to the graph after the upper plot, it will be drawn in front. The opaque fill will cover the fill from the plot behind it.